# Msg 39011 SQL Server was unable to communicate with the LaunchPad service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I was playing with the new "R" scripting in SQL Server 2016 CTP 30. 
Finally got it working, thanks to this site.

I've had a problem that I'm sure others will run into as well.

All of a sudden the "R" scripts no longer worked, they returned this error:

> Msg 39011, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   SQL Server was unable to communicate with the LaunchPad service. Please verify the configuration of the service.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to move TempDB to a disk with more space, I had to restart the server.

This stopped the SQL Server as well as SQL Agent, and the new "SQL Server Launchpad".

It was easy to restart SQL Server and SQL Agent. 
To restart LaunchPad, I needed to go to

Administrative Tools -> Services 
and find "SQL Server LaunchPad (MSSQLSERVER)"

right-click it and select "Start"
and my scripts run again.

Comment: Does this apply to the newer versions too - SQL Server 2016 RC3?

Comment: I've checked SQL Server 2016 RTM, The SQL Server Launchpad still exist, but it is started when restarting the SQL Server.

Comment: It is usually considered best practice to start and stop SQL Server related services using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: @JidiSQL; it might be a good place to do so, but even the new version 18 of SSMS has an "Restart" option in Object Explorer on the server. And restarting the server should also restart all services. It didn't then (in November 2015), but it works as expected today (May 2019).

Comment: @HenrikStaunPoulsen, To run the Python it's issue the same. Untill unless you will not start the 'SQL Server Launchpad' service. For Launchpad Service +1